# Matching problem expectation and variance

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

**The matching problem**: Suppose $n$ gentlemen go out for dinner and leave their hats in the cloakroom.  After the dinner (and several glasses of wine) they pick their hats completely randomly.  Denote by $X$ the number of gentlemen who take their own hats.  Find $E[X]$ and $Var[X]$.

I have seen many answers to this:

$E[X] = \sum_i^nE(I_i)= \sum_i^n 1/n = 1$,

where $I_i$ is the indicator for each person which equals $1$ if the person takes his hat own hat and $0$ otherwise.

I don't understand how the probability of $I_i$ can be $1/n$ for all of $I_i$.  Consider the third gentleman to take a hat; wouldn't the probability he take his hat be $1/(n-3)$ rather than $1/n$?

Comment: If you consider each person individually, the probability is $1/n$. It doesn't matter whether these variables are independent or not (which is your concern of the changing probabilities), because the property of "linearity of expectation" works either way.

Comment: Alternatively, you can think of each gentleman selecting a hat *at the same time*, so there is no reduction in the number of alternatives $n$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork what happens if 2 people select the same hat?

Comment: @ObnoxiousFrog Whatever random process settles choice conflicts, that process does not "favor" one gentleman over another and hence does not affect the probabilities.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Hot damn. Is there anything I can read about this?

Comment: Many long years ago I read **Mathematics of Choice:  How to count without counting** by Ivan Niven, which was particularly lucid on these kinds of conceptual issues.

Comment: Thanks man! ill go check it out

Comment: Suppose they pick hats sequentially. Then $P(I_1=1)=\frac 1 n$ and $P(I_2=1)=P(I_1=1)P(I_2=1|I_1=1)+P(I_1=0)P(I_2=1|I_1=0)=\frac 1 n$. This should convince you that it's $1/n$ for the rest as well and order of picking doesn't matter.

Comment: Also just consider the last person picking a hat: he is not guaranteed to get his own hat 1/(n-(n-1))=1. Your model would be correct if we were modeling the probability the 3rd gentleman got his hat if we also know the first 3 did not get that hat. Or alternatively, maybe there's 1 "lucky" hat we're interested in, and if the first 3 gentlemen did not pick it, we have 1/(n-3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite.
$X = I_1+\dotsb+I_n$, so
$$E[X] = E[I_1+\dotsb+I_n] =E[I_1]+\dotsb+E[I_n] = n\cdot E[I_1] = n\cdot\frac{1}{n} = 1,$$
since
\begin{align*}
E[I_k] &= 0\cdot P(I_k = 0)+1\cdot P(I_k = 1) \\
&= P(I_k = 1),
\end{align*}
and $P(I_k = 1) = \frac{1}{n}$.

---

Think about it this way, pretend each person is sitting in a line and the each hat has been labeled to match the correct person. With indicators, it is like you distribute each ticket back randomly face down to each person. So the chance that person $k$ got the correct ticket is $\frac{1}{n}$. In this manner, we bar people from choosing the same hat.

Comment: That is the part I dont understand why is the expectation 1/n

Comment: @ObnoxiousFrog Ok, so first, you made a mistake. Second, you have a misunderstanding. Your calculation was wrong above. Recall that $P(I_k = 1) =  E[I_K].$ Thus $n\cdot E[I_k] = n\cdot\frac{1}{n} = 1$.

Comment: @ObnoxiousFrog $E[I_k] = 0\cdot P(I_k = 0)+1\cdot P(I_k = 1) = P(I_k = 1).$$

Comment: @ObnoxiousFrog $P(I_k = 1)$ is the chance that person $k$ chooses his hat correctly, and he only has a $\frac{1}{n}$ to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a computation that nobody seems to want to write that I think clears up the confusion directly. Let’s suppose the men choose the hats in order, removing hats one at a time. The chance that the first man chooses his own hat is clearly $\frac1n$. Now let $Y_1$ be the indicator function of whether the first man has chosen the second man’s hat and $Y_2$ be the indicator of whether the second man chooses his own hat.
Then the chance that the second man chooses his own hat is

$P(Y_2)=P(Y_2|Y_1 = 1)P(Y_1=1)+P(Y_2|Y_1=0)P(Y_1=0)=0\cdot\frac1n+\frac1{n-1}\cdot\frac{n-1}n=\frac1n$.

Now onto the third man. Let $Y_1$, $Y_2$ and $Y_3$ now denote the indicators of whether the first, second or third man have chosen the *third* man’s hat. Then $P(Y_1)+P(Y_2)=\frac1n+\frac{n-1}n\cdot\frac1{n-1}=\frac2n$ and

$P(Y_3)=P(Y_3|Y_1=1\text{ or }Y_2=1)(P(Y_1)+P(Y_2))+P(Y_3|Y_1=0\text{ and }Y_2=0)P(Y_1=0\text{ and }Y_2=0) = 0\cdot\frac2n+\frac1{n-2}(1-\frac2n)=\frac1n,\text{ etc.}$